# RBAC/LDAP for Spinnaker

Tags: spinnaker

Are there near-term plans to incorporate LDAP authentication into Spinnaker and incorporate role-based access controls throughout the platform? Specifically, we would like to be able to control through our existing LDAP groups who can provision servers, security groups, applications, etc; also control the human approval step in a pipeline to restrict that to specific users on a per-pipeline level...really we're looking for the granularity of IAM roles in AWS (or the ability to leverage existing IAM roles)

Answer (score 3):

Spinnaker supports configurable authentication via SAML at the API layer. All the services behind the API layer would typically be protected via HTTPS client auth and only directly callable by other Spinnaker services.

The current authentication model in Spinnaker is only based around restricting modifications to specific accounts (A Spinnaker installation can manage multiple accounts across multiple cloud providers). An account can be configured with a `requiredGroupMemberships` in which case, the authenticated user must be a member of the group (as provided by the SAML authentication configuration) in order to be able to mutate that account (new deploys, load balancers, security groups).

We don't currently have plans for anything more fine grained than that.

Here is a [great writeup](http://riltsken.github.io/devops/infrastructure/deploymenttools/2015/12/08/setup-okta-saml-with-spinnaker.html) of how to enable SAML auth in Spinnaker